# How can draw this? i only get to do this

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, draw, technical-drawing, pst-labo

[image]

Hello I have managed to draw this, but I am not able to draw the rest, any help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\newcommand{\pstClamp}{
    \colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
    % potence
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.5,-2.625)(-.25,13)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,8)(1.75,7.75)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,8.25)(-.75,7.5)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.375,7.875){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1.5,8.15)(3,7.6)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,4)(1.75,3.75)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,4.25)(-.75,3.5)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.375,3.875){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1.5,4.15)(3,3.6)
    % support elevateur
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](.25,-.25)(3.25,-1.25)(.25,-2.25)(1.25,-2.25)(4.25,-1.25)(1.25,-.25)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](4.25,-.25)(1.25,-1.25)(4.25,-2.25)(3.25,-2.25)(.25,-1.25)(3.25,-.25)
    \psline(.25,-1.25)(4.5,-1.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](4.5,-1)(4.75,-1.5)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0)(4.5,-.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,-2.25)(4.5,-2.5)
    % base
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,-2.5)(5,-2.75)
}

\begin{document}


\pstDosage[niveauReactifBurette=10, niveauLiquide1=80,]

\pstClamp




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use pst-labo package.

Comment: I am using it but I am not able to add the missing parts

Comment: I not saw the package. I'm sorry. Sincerely I have not understood the addendum to the image done with the blue color.

Comment: I mean missing the thermometer and syringe

Comment: Your first image shows a thermometer that measures the temperature inside of the heating/cooling bath, while the blue hand-drawn additions in your second image show a thermometer that measures the temperature inside of the reaction vessel. Which of the two would you actually like to draw?

Comment: I really would like to draw the first picture but I don't quite understand this package yet